# Lazy generation of pairs of adjacent elements in a "circular list"

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, circular-list

To check for ray-triangle collisions, we can first see if the ray collides with the triangle's plane. If it does, we then check if the intersection point is on the same side for all triangle sides. If true, this means that the point is inside the triangle. This procedure is analogous for rectangles and other convex figures.

This is a list of vertexes belonging to a rectangle (counter-clockwise ordered):

```
vertexes = [ll, lr, ur, ul]
```

and I want to generate a list with all its sides; that is, all adjacent pairs of vertexes:

```
vertexPairs = [(ll, lr), (lr, ur), (ur, ul), (ul, ll)]
```

(note that the last vertex, *ul*, also pairs with the first one, *ll*)

How can I **lazily** generate such a list for a generic convex geometric figure, assuming I have an ordered list of its vertexes?

---

The idea is to feed each of the pairs to a function, *isInside*, and check if all of its return values are the same. This is what I'm doing:

```
1.  vertexes = [<list of vertexes>]
2.  vertexPairs = ???
3.  results = map (\(v1, v2) -> isInside point v1 v2) vertexPairs
4.  allequal = all (== head results) (tail results)
```

Because Haskell is lazy, if a call to *isInside* returns a value that differs from the first call's return value, the call to *all* ends (line 4). Similarly, I wanted a way to generate the *vertexPairs* list in a lazy way.

---

As I was writing this question, I thought of a **possible solution** to generate the pairs:

```
vertexPairs = zip (vertexes) (tail vertexes ++ [head vertexes])
```

1. Is this lazy? I would say so, as it doesn't use *last* or similar functions, but I'm still relatively new to Haskell.
2. It also looks a bit ugly, thanks to the concatenation and
   single-element list. Is there a better way?
3. As a related question, what should be the free-point notation for line 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this way of generating the list is lazy. In general, list functions in Haskell are lazy.

You can test whether it's lazy yourself by including something that will error out (e.g. `undefined`) in the initial list. For example, if

```
vertexes = [(0,0), (10,0), undefined, undefined]
```

then `vertexPairs` will give you an error (since it needs to evaluate the whole list to print it). However, if it's lazy, `head vertexPairs` should still give you the correct pair--and it does!

I think your code actually looks rather good. The `tail vertexes ++ [head vertex]` makes what you're doing very clear. Yes, it looks a little odd to use `++` here, but it makes sense: appending to the end of the list is an expensive operation, so it should stand out. I can't think of any better way to write that code. As a minor style hint, you can drop the parentheses around `vertexes`:

```
vertexPairs = zip vertexes (tail vertexes ++ [head vertexes])
```

For 3., conceptually, you want to apply `isInside point` to each pair. Right now it has a type like `Point -> Point -> Bool`. You want to get a function that takes its first two arguments as a tuple: `(Point, Point) -> Bool`. This function is called `uncurry` because the opposite transformation (turning a function that expects a tuple into one of multiple parameters) is called currying. So you could write 3. like this:

```
results = map (uncurry (isInside point)) vertexPairs
```

Comment: Very clear answer, thank you. I guess it's a good thing that my solution wasn't that bad after all :)

Answer (score 4):

Though tikhon has answered most questions, if you want to write it in a slightly prettier way, you could do

`vertexPairs v = zip v (tail $ cycle v)`

This works since `zip` stops generating a list when one of its arguments "run out"

Comment: Hah, I was about to comment, but `olianta` s reponse came up. I had a similar suggestion but also the frivolous point-free version `vertexPairs = zip  <*> tail . cycle` which may amuse